# Angular 5.2 : Getting error while building application using VSTS build server : CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, npm

Suddenly builds started failing with following error :

> 2019-01-03T12:57:22.2223175Z **EXEC : FATAL error : CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory** 
>   
>  error MSB3073: The command "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod" exited with code 3.

I have tried all the solutions available like  : 
1) Updating the virtual memory of Windows 
2) Updating the NPM version and Node version 
3) Also tried adding command to increase **--max_old_space_size**

Still facing the same issue while Publishing the angular APP. It works on local  but failing on build server while publishing
On local getting following error :

```
    <--- Last few GCs --->

[2212:000002BC74FB20D0]   152613 ms: Mark-sweep 1411.4 (1466.9) -> 1411.4 (1466.9) MB, 2117.6 / 0.0 ms  last resort GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0000032354625EE1 <JSObject>
    1: bindContainer [node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~22960] [pc=000003AD4C9DBFB9](this=000000063100BE21 <JSGlobal Object>,node=000001B7FE6A7E61 <NodeObject map = 0000020A3EA721A1>,containerFlags=45)
    2: visitNodeArray [node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:~15947] [pc=000003AD4C9A32A5](this=000000063100BE21 <JSGloba...
```

Comment: You say you've tried using the `--max-old-space-size` option (note: no underscores). How did you run that command, was it something like this? `node --max-old-space-size=8192 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod`

Comment: @RobC yes i have added that in Package.json under script section but still got the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the memory allocated for the execution application is less than the required memory when run application, by default Node allocates a certain size of memory.

You can increase this size for every build changing your **package.json**, so even local or in the server the application will prepare the publish with ideal size of memory allocation.

```
"build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
```

Another option is inside your npm folder, edit the ng.cmd to always increase the memory size.

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe" --max_old_space_size=8192 "%~dp0\..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
) ELSE (
 @SETLOCAL
 @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
 node --max_old_space_size=8192 "%~dp0\..\@angular\cli\bin\ng" %*
)
```

And a less elegant solution is using a dependency that handle this problem.
Run from the root location of your project:

```
npm install -g increase-memory-limit
increase-memory-limit
```

In the server you will need to make a script for these steps before the publish.
More details about the package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/increase-memory-limit

Comment: Are you using Node v8+ ? You can try change the NODE_OPTIONS env variable to set the max_old_space_size globally.


export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

More details here: https://github.com/endel/increase-memory-limit

Comment: Do you know how to and where to set that, check the stack trace i have updated the question

Comment: If you are using a Linux/MAC environment, you can add a script to run that bash command and check if the variable was set with "echo $NODE_OPTIONS".

For Windows use set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

Comment: When i Use command : "build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod. For this to run i have used NPM RUN build then getting error on local : The build command requires to be run in an Angular project, but a project definition could not be found.

Comment: And BUild Server do not have ng.cmd file

Comment: This option `"build": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod` should be overwritten in your Package.json inside your Angular Application. And make sure when run the "npm run build" you need be in the same folder as your project.json file.

Comment: Also, some people with similar problem solved using the build with Ahead of Time of Compilation -  `npm run build / ng build --prod --aot false`.